# What is the best place to put Android Location listeners? Activity or Application class?

Tags: android, google-play-services, geofencing, android-geofence

I am working on an application that requires user's **current location**. All application is based on user's location.

Once the user opens the app, I retrieve their **current location** and use it. If they leave the application, I decrease `minInterval` and keep requesting user's location in background. I will need their location for my geofencing feature.

I have several activities in the application. Since I need the user's location in Application level, would that be a good approach to place it in **Application** class or is it better to keep it in a top level **Activity**?

Thanks

Comment: its better make it as a Service. and make a local Broadcast.

Comment: When I was doing this, I called my LocationService inside the application instance. Then when you get your app instance somewhere in your activity, just call the respective method to get user location - you could show a progress dialog because it could take a few seconds